MassTransit + RabbitMQ как настроить обменники?
Пытаюсь публиковать все сообщения в один обменник, которые будут раскидываться дальше в очереди по routing key, но почему-то создаются обменник с названием очереди.
Пытаюсь сделать как-то так:
cfg.Message<FirstMessagePart1>(p => p.SetEntityName("first_part1"));
cfg.Publish<FirstMessagePart1>(p =>
{
    p.Durable = true;
    p.AutoDelete = false;
    p.BindQueue("first_exchange", "first_part1_queue");
});

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("first_part1_queue", x =>
{
    x.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
    x.Bind("first_exchange", b =>
    {
        b.RoutingKey = "1";
        b.AutoDelete = false;
        b.Durable = true;
    });
    x.Consumer<FirstMessagePart1Consumer>(hostContext);
});

Получается то, что я и хочу, НО(!) создаются еще обменники с названием очереди:

Которые в свою очередь уже отправляют это всё в очередь:

Почему MassTransit создает эти обменники, а не делает напрямую это всё? Как можно (но нужно ли?) отключить это поведение?

Поясните, вы хотите чтобы ваше сообщение перехватывал 1 обменник и отправлял это дальше по всем остальным? Почему сразу не публиковать 1 сообщение, которое автоматически будет попадать во все обменники. При таком раскладе у всех обменников должна быть своя очередь

@pashagoroshko Так расписал же всё, 2 сообщения через 1 обменник, но в разные очереди ‍♂️

Это невозможно на данный момент!
Создатели MassTransit пишут:

"MassTransit will always declare exchanges, queues, and bindings.
There is no way to disable this behavior."

Ссылка на обсуждение.

Ответ не по теме. Вопрос был не "как полностью запретить создавать обменники и очереди"
